# Is there a shorthand way to write the Javascript code 'a||"text"' in Java?

Tags: java

When I need to display a value that might be null/undefined in Javascript, I usually just write:
`console.log(a||"");`

Or something similar.  Is there a similar way to do this in Java other than:

`System.out.println(a!=null?a:"");`

Comment: In C# ((string)null).ToString() actually returns an emtpy string. Might be the same in java, try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do besides using the ternary operator is to create a very short method to do the same. Perhaps "ns" for "nullable string":

```
public static String ns(String nullableString) {
    return nullableString == null ? "" : nullableString;
}
```

Then you can write "System.out.println(ns(a));" However, the ternary operator is clearer - I would only do something like the above if I were doing this all over the place.

Comment: I think I'll end up using this solution since null Strings are quite common in this application.

Answer (score 3):

I think that your `System.out.println(a!=null?a:"");` is a very clear way to output what you are looking for.

It uses the ternary operator and seems to make sense.

```
(condition) ? (if true) : (if false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have ternaries:
a != null ? a : ""

Answer (score 0):

If the variable is not initialized, java will not compile.  Undefined is unacceptable in Java.

If you have a variable named "blueberry" and you want to display the value on the console, you can do this:

```
System.out.println(blueberry);
```

This code will display "null" on the console if blueberry is null.

Here is a simple demonstration

```
public class Outty
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String blueberry = null;

        System.out.println(blueberry);

        blueberry = "7";
        System.out.println(blueberry);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't, as the others answers suggest. That is because in JS, boolean operators don't necessarily return booleans, they return the value of the object that caused the expression  to short-circuit. However, in Java, as in C and other languages, boolean operators always return boolean, so you don't have that convenient way of defaulting a value `a = b || c`  or to prevent a null pointer `a = b && b.getValue()`

Answer (score 0):

You can do a function that doesn't print null when its null.
I don't know java but a prototype will be

```
function safePrint(object a)
{
    System.out.println(a!=null?a:"");
}
```

and then just write

```
safePrint(a);
```

Although if you are looking for short code use an interpreted language like javascript or perl. compiled languages like java is just not meant for fast and short coding.